# Is there a way to make an AutoHotKey script to make the mouse "travel" according to where your mouse is on your screen?

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a line of code that allows the mouse to travel (actually move and not "jump" to), from a specific point on the screen to another point? It would be much appreciated if someone could show me how to. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Speed` parameter in [MouseMove](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) to some higher number and then your mouse wont move instantly.

Example:
Press <kbd>F1</kbd> to move your mouse to random location on your screen.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

F1::
    Random, x, 0, A_ScreenWidth
    Random, y, 0, A_ScreenHeight
    MouseMove, % x, % y, 15
return
```

Comment: Hmm... but would it be possible to "move" your mouse, say, 15 pixels to the right, of where the mouse currently is. Say the mouse is at 0,0; would it be possible to create a script to move it to 15,0? Thanks <3

Comment: That is exactly what the parameter `Relative` in `MouseMove` does. `MouseMove, 15, 0, 15, R` (Move 15 pixels on the x-axis with a speed of 15)

Comment: @user14291648 Please ask that comment as a new question.

Comment: @Spyre Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: @user14291648 Its fine, just mb note that asking follow-up questions as a comment will make it less likely to be answered than if it was its own, standalone, question